# Native method in R to test if file is ascii

Tags: r, cran

Is there a native method in R to test if a file on disk is an ASCII text file, or a binary file? Similar to the `file` command in Linux, but a method that will work cross platform?

The `file.info()` function can distinguish a file from a dir, but it doesn't seem to go beyond that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If all you care about is whether the file is ASCII or binary...

Well, first up definitions. All files are binary at some level:

```
is.binary <- function(file){
  if(system.type() != "quantum computer"){
    return(TRUE) 
  }else{
    return(cat=alive&dead)
  }
}
```

ASCII is just an encoding system for characters. It is therefore impossible to tell if a file is ASCII or binary, because ASCII-ness is a matter of interpretation. If I save a file and decide that binary number 01001101 is Q and 01001110 is Z then you might decode this as ASCII but you'll get the wrong message. Luckily the Americans muscled in and said "Hey, everyone use ASCII to code their text! You get 128 characters and a parity bit! Woo! Go USA!". IBM tried to tell people to use EBCDIC but nobody listened. Which was A Good Thing.

So everyone was packing ASCII-coded text into their 8-bit bytes, and using the eighth bit for parity checking. But then people stopped doing parity checking because TCP/IP handled all that, which was also A Good Thing, and the eighth bit was expected to be zero. If not, there was trouble.

Because people (read "Microsoft") started abusing the eighth bit, and making up their own encoding schemes, and so unless you knew what encoding scheme the file was using, you were stuffed. And the file very rarely told you what encoding scheme it was. And now we have Unicode and even more encoding schemes. And that is a third Good Thing. But I digress.

Nowadays when people ask if a file is binary, what they are normally asking is "Does any byte in this file have it's highest bit set?". Which you can do in R by reading a raw file connection as unsigned integers and testing the highest value. Something like:

```
is.binary <- function(filepath,max=1000){
  f=file(filepath,"rb",raw=TRUE)
  b=readBin(f,"int",max,size=1,signed=FALSE)
  return(max(b)>128)
}
```

This will by default test only at most the first 1000 characters. I think the `file` command does something similar.

You may want to change the test to check for printable character codes, and whitespace, and line feed, carriage return, and other codes you might want to consider plausible in your non-binary files...

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for explaining how ascii files are a subset of binary files. Could you add a line to `is.binary` to close the connection after reading the file?

Comment: Could you explain which character causes `is.binary(system.file("NEWS", package="reshape2"))` to be TRUE?

Comment: "José Bartolomei Díaz". This file is UTF-8 encoded Unicode code points, most likely. Its not ASCII-encoded text.

Comment: For text vs. non-text, wouldn't it make more sense to check for ASCII control characters 0-7 and 14-27 inclusive? If you find those you can be pretty sure it's not an ASCII or UTF-8 file, right? And UTF-16 should only add 00 to the allowed set of values. I'm not an expert in encodings though...

Answer (score 1):

Well, how would you do that?  I guess you can't without reading (parts or all of) the file, which is why files **extensions** are used to signal content type.

I looked into that years ago---and as I recall, the `file(1)` apps actually reads the first few header bytes of a file and compares that to what is stored in a lookup table.  Sounds like a good candidate for an add-on package to me..

Comment: On Linux, you can find more information on this in `magic(5)`.

Comment: Yes, thanks, that is *precisely* the lookup table I referred to. On my system, `/etc/magic` is provided by `libmagic1` off the source package `file` -- precisely what Jeroen is going to use for his forthcoming 'filemagic' package :)

Comment: Yeah, but file *extensions*  are fungible.  It's one thing to test for the way a file appears to be defined, another to test based on header metadata (take a peek at the top of, say, a PDF and there are a bunch of definition strings that have to be correct, regardless of filename extension, for Acrobat to accept the file), and yet another to deal with a file as @Spacedman does in his answer.

Comment: @Carl, did you read what I wrote?  I suggested a content-based approach just as `file(1)` does, with comparison against known headers.

Comment: Dirk,  I didn't mean to denigrate your response.  I probably should have put my comment under the question rather than your answer.  Apologies.

Comment: No worries, I just wanted to make sure we didn't talk past each other.

Comment: Yes an R interface to magic would be great. But the library seems to be linux/bsd only?

Comment: Why would that be a problem? ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The example section of the manual for `?raw` uses this:

```
isASCII <-  function(txt) all(charToRaw(txt) <= as.raw(127))
```